# What is the best method to reuse animations for cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to be able to allocate a few actions so that I can use and reuse them again and again on whatever target CCNode I want. I assumed I could just load them up with a generic NSObject class in an init then call them when nessicary from a method but was unable to.

Was I just inept at my attempt or is there a more elegant solution?

```
@implementation Animation

@synthesize animation;

-(id) init 
{
    if ( (self=[super init]) ) {
        animation = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration: 0.15 scale: 2.0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) myAnimation
{
    return animation;
}

[targetCCNode runAction:[Animation myAnimation]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation an action is very fast. I don't think it's reasonable. If you want just to create actions with some common configuration then I suggest you to create (or use an existing one) a class with static methods for creating this actions. Or a singleton with non-static methods if you require some context when creating actions

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense. I think I was over thinking it and trying to preload everything as much as possible even though the need had not arisen.

Comment: @Sup: If your game use a lot of resources it's impossible to preload them all together because you will use to much memory in this case. I thing you are using cocos cashes for this and they will automatically release old resources if you will preload to much